# Slow Startup and Shutdown on KDE

Tags: arch-linux, kde

I'm using *KDE* and when I log in after entering user password, it takes almost 4-5 seconds to system to show desktop. While, when i shutdown, it takes almost 10 seconds to properly shutdown. But if i use $shutdown now command, the system shutdowns immediately. These slow login and shutdown and times were not there before i switched to *Arch+KDE*

Comment: the commentary underneath the question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625989/why-do-my-computers-take-a-long-time-to-shut-down  shows the probable cause (systemd waits 2mn waiting for something to finish properly, before killing it brutally (which doesn't let the process(es) time to write files, etc). You need to determine what hangs...)